# Wait untill all the resorces are loaded (in the network tab) and then load css

Tags: javascript

What i want to do is to wait until EVERYTHING is loaded, every single file in the network tab on the devbar. and only then load my css file.

I'm using Gumroad's embedded product on my static website, and I can only change the css after everything is loaded to the dom.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log('page is fully loaded');
});
```